# How to multiply a value fetched from one API to the array of values fetched from other api?

Tags: node.js, ethereum, fetch-api, smartcontracts

A contract consists of a number of tokens with different balances. I am using an API to get the information about the tokens present in it in an array. Information I am getting is given below:

```
    "token_address": "0x2d30ca6f024dbc1307ac8a1a44ca27de6f797ec22ef20627a1307243b0ab7d09",
    "name": "Kylin Network",
    "symbol": "KYL",
    "decimals": "18",
    "balance": "123456789"
  }]
```

I want to use the address of each token to call another api to get the current price of the token and multiply it with the balance present in the information above. Here is my code :

```
var add = "0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82"
var tokens = [];
fetch(`https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/account/erc20/balances?chain=bsc&chain_name=mainnet&address=${add}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': 'unT7o....bgF6fVAgNW6AU',
        'Accept': '*/*',
    }
}).then(res => res.json()).then(json => json.map(item => {
    tokens.push(item.token_address);

    tokens.forEach((token) => fetch(`https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/token/ERC20/${token}/price?chain=bsc&chain_name=mainnet&providerUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fthrjqwgeodkr.usemoralis.com%3A2053%2Fserver`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-API-KEY': 'unT7...........rZhbgF6fVAgNW6AU',
            'Accept': '*/*',
        }
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data.usdPrice)));
}))
```

I am getting promise pending for some of the tokens. Is there an issue with the code?

Answer (score 0):

That code is pretty unreadable. Instead of using promise chaining and getting the issues like you are, I would suggest an async await approach which achieves the same thing as promise chaining in a more readable manner. The below is to get you started, but I think you need to do some more reading/research first.

```
var add = '0x0e09fabb73bd3ade0a17ecc321fd13a19e81ce82'
const fetchOne = await(
  await fetch(
    `https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/account/erc20/balances?chain=bsc&chain_name=mainnet&address=${add}`,
    {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': 'unT7o....bgF6fVAgNW6AU',
        Accept: '*/*',
      },
    },
  ),
).json()

const tokens = fetchOne.map((item) => item.token_address)

const data = await Promise.all(
  tokens.map((token) => {
    return fetch(
      `https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/token/ERC20/${token}/price?chain=bsc&chain_name=mainnet&providerUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fthrjqwgeodkr.usemoralis.com%3A2053%2Fserver`,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'X-API-KEY': 'unT7...........rZhbgF6fVAgNW6AU',
          Accept: '*/*',
        },
      },
    ).json()
  }),
)
```